# php replace between strings like „ or &ldquor; or &#x0201E; or &#8222;

Tags: php, html, replace, entities

I like to **php** replace this String:

`This String is called „Foo“ or „Bar“ but could be formatted as &ldquor;Foo&#8220; or even &#8222;Bar&#x0201C; and many more combinations.`

with some kind of *BB Code*

`This String is called [quote=Foo] or [quote=Bar] but could be formatted as [quote=Foo] or even [quote=Bar] and many more combinations.`

I try to replace `„` and `“` with `&#8222;` and `&#8220;` in php but that wasn't work at all.

I don't even know how to start at all :/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your input string, normalize the escape sequences by un-encoding them, then a simple RegEx should work.

```php
// Original string
$s1 = <<<EOD
This String is called „Foo“ or „Bar“ but could be formatted as &ldquor;Foo&#8220; or even &#8222;Bar&#x0201C; and many more combinations.
EOD;

// Normalize entities
$s2 = html_entity_decode($s1, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML5);

// Convert to bbCode-like style
$s3 = preg_replace(
    '/„(.*?)“/',
    '[quote=$1]',
    $s2
    );

print_r($s3);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/Dfig0

Comment: So easy... Working. Thanks a lot.